# Checkbox will not stay checked and submit listener does not work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, handlebars.js

I am dynamically rendering pages using Handlebars.js, and I have a "quiz-form template" with the following code: [image]

```
<div id="right-pane">
        <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="quiz-form-template">
            <form class="cf" id="quiz-form">
                <h2>Create a <span>quiz</span></h2>
                <p>Enter a quiz name and description to get started.</p>

                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="quiz-name" placeholder="Quiz Name" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="quiz-description"
                        placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div id="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_random" />  Create randomly generated quiz <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_single_page" />  Render quiz on a single page <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_immediate"/>  Give immediate feedback <br/>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Questions" /> 

            </form>
        </script>
    </div>
```

I am running into *two* problems that I have been trying to debug to no avail. After rendering this page on my html, when I click the checkboxes, they do not get checked at all. It seems like I click and it "almost bounces off".

Additionally when I click the submit button, it is not being listened to. I am console.log"ging" to check and their is not output. Here is my event listener:

```
rightPane.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    console.log( event.target );
    event.preventDefault;

    if ( event.target.value === "Add Questions" ) {

        //DOM elements
        newQuizName = document.querySelector('#quiz-form input');
        newDescription = document.querySelector('#quiz-form textarea');
        randomStatus = document.querySelector('#quiz-form input[name="is_random"]');
        singlePageStatus = document.querySelector('#quiz-form input[name="is_single_page"]');
        immediateStatus = document.querySelector('#quiz-form input[name="is_immediate"]');

        var pendingQuiz = getPendingQuiz();
        pendingQuizMetaData = {name: newQuizName.value, description: newDescription.value, 
            random: randomStatus.checked, singlePage: singlePageStatus.checked, 
            immediate: immediateStatus.checked 


        pendingQuiz = { metadata: pendingQuizMetaData, questions: [] };
        updatePendingQuiz( pendingQuiz );
        rightPane.innerHTML = templates.renderQuestionType();

        newQuestion = "";
        newSubject = "";
        // }

        // Since add questions is clicked, we should send the user to select question type

        // we'll need to render html on the right pane

    } 

});
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is code handling click on checkboxes?

Comment: Even before the code is handled in the script, in the browser, the checkboxes appear but I am not able to check them. So my problem is not with the handling.

Comment: So this can be a CSS issue if it's not a script. The second question is simple though, but the first is impossible to answer without seeing it happening.

Comment: as dfsq says, what happens if (without loading the js files) you try and click the checkboxes?  and if relevant, could you post some of your CSS file?  it might hold the key to that first part.

Comment: So, I commented out my entire css file and I am getting the same result. I am simply unable to check any of the boxes. I also submitted my javascript file into a syntax validator and it seemed fine.

Comment: The problem is with the templating <script></script> because when I just put the code beginning with <form> and ending with </form> I was able to check the boxes.